# How to change text-encoding to iso-8859-1 in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, character-encoding

My visual studio is now saving files in utf-8. How do i configure visual studio to save it iso-8859-1?

Comment: What's wrong with UTF-8? It's basically the standard nowadays since Latin1 is limited.

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio, File -> Advanced Save Options -> in "Encoding" select "Western European (ISO) - Codepage 28591".

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171439%28office.11%29.aspx) page, iso-8859-1 is called 28591 in MS lingo

Comment: I don't see Advanced Save Options in File

Comment: by default it's between "Save As..." and "Save All" in File menu.  If you do not have it, you probably customized your menu, and therefore you need to bring it back: Right-click on the menu, select "Customize" (the last menu item) and find "Advanced Save Options..." item in "File" category

Comment: It only exists when a file is open, and works only on that file. So this doesn't answer the question.